# exception in java: write in a output file

Tags: java, exception, treeset

what is:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.TreeMap$KeyIterator
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source) ???
```

what I try is to write in a output file an object of a class which has like attributes

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private TreeSet<Product> tree = new TreeSet<Product>();
private Iterator<Product> iterator ;
```

and this class implements `Serializable`.

```
public void scrieArbore() {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream outStreamWarehouse = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(WAREHOUSE_FILENAME)));
        outStreamWarehouse.writeObject(h);

        outStreamWarehouse.flush();

        outStreamWarehouse.close();

        System.out.println("Safely written warehouse");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `Iterator<Product> iterator` field. [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) doesn't implement `Serializable`.

A way to solve this problem would be marking this field as `transient`.

```
private transient Iterator<Product> iterator;
```